# How do you make values auto-increment in headers?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I've created a macro that adds a page at the end of a document and changes the title text in the Header. I want to be able to add multiple pages and have the letter in the title auto-increment:

SCHEDULE 'A'
SCHEDULE 'B'
SCHEDULE 'C'
etc.

I tried using an AUTONUM field, but I get a notification that says, "**Main Document Only.**"

```
Sub AddSchedule()
'
' AddSchedue Macro
' Press Ctrl+End to add a schedule to a Policy.
'

    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
' Unlink Header from Previous - Is this necessary? The macro seems to work without it...   
    Selection.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=2).Range.Text = "SCHEDULE '"
    Selection.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=2).Range.Select
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
    Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "AUTONUM  \* ALPHABETIC \s ' ", PreserveFormatting:=False
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument


End Sub
```

How can I get my page titles to auto-increment in the Headers?

Also, I was under the assumption that I needed to unlink my headers from previous in my macro. I couldn't get that part to work, but with the exception of the fields not working right, everything else seems to work just fine. The header displays the new title even though it says it's still linked. Should I just leave it? Or how would I go about unlinking me headers? I tried using:

```
Selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious = False
```

But it gives me this runtime error:

> The method or property is not available because the current selection
>   is locked for format changes

Comment: I can get some other fields to work in the header, I can make it work with Section Numbers, but the first Schedule would be in Section 3, so the letter displays as a 'C' for the first Schedule.

Comment: And I have to figure out the unlink to previous part, it works until you get to another page then it updates the other headers to match the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without a macro by using a calculated field in your header instead - you were very close with the use of the section field.  Just need to subtract 2 so it displays right value.

[image]

The section 3 header would need to be unlinked from previous section before you insert the field, but subsequent sections could be linked and the schedule number would update automatically (eg in section 4, the heading would say Schedule 2).